What I am doing wrong with sphinx autosummary to generate docs
When I am trying to generate docs for my code. I have a very strange issue. Can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!
My aim is to create quite deep docs for my package. Such this.

Every Class is clickable and etc.
First of all my conf.py file, index.md (I am using myst_parser)
The catalog structure is:

conf.py
import os
import sys
import va_sdk

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../va_sdk'))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = va_sdk.__name__
release = va_sdk.__version__

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'myst_parser',
    'autodocsumm',
]
source_suffix = {
    '.rst': 'restructuredtext',
    '.md': 'markdown',
}
napoleon_google_docstring = True
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
autosummary_generate = True

# numpydoc_class_members_toctree = False

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

html_theme = 'sphinxawesome_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']

md_pages/Documentation.rst
Welcome to My Toolbox
=====================

Some words.

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :recursive:

   va_sdk

autosummary/base.rst
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. auto{{ objtype }}:: {{ objname }}

autosummary/class.rst
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}
   :show-inheritance:

   {% block methods %}
   .. automethod:: __init__

   {% if methods %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Methods') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in methods %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Attributes') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in attributes %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

index.md
# SDK Видеоаналитики

## Содержание

'''{toctree}
:maxdepth: 2

md_pages/Документация пакета va_sdk
md_pages/Архитектура
md_pages/Использование
md_pages/Конфигурация_проекта
'''

autosummary/module.rst
{{ fullname | escape | underline }}

.. rubric:: Description

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ fullname }}

{% if classes %}
.. rubric:: Classes

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: .
    {% for class in classes %}
    {{ class }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% if functions %}
.. rubric:: Functions

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: .
    {% for function in functions %}
    {{ function }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

First of all I will explain the process I am generating docs.

I change name of the ./_templates/autosummary dir, for example to ./_templates/autosummary2
Run $./make.bat html command
I change name back from ./_templates/autosummary2 dir, to ./_templates/autosummary
Run $./make.bat html command

In conclusion after points 1-2. There no any links deeper in docs The result is:

In conclusion after points 1-4. It created deeper links in docs The result is:

If I will do just points 3-4. The documentation don't generate deep docs at all There will be such result.

